# Mysql Get Row Positions

Tags: mysql

I already checked others stack-overflows questions, but none explain how to do the following:

I have an application to control reservations queue and I need to list for each row:

`positionTotal` - Represents the position based on all active(status) rows with lower id.
`positionSamePeople` - Represents the position based on all active(status) rows with lower id and the same people number.

---

reservation Table:

```
+---------------------------------------+
+ id INT AI                             +
+ status TINYINT (0-Inactive/1-Active)  +
+ people INT                            +
+---------------------------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation
+----------------------+
+ id | status | people +
+----------------------+
+ 1  |    1   |    3   +
+ 2  |    0   |    1   +
+ 4  |    1   |    3   +
+ 6  |    1   |    1   +
+ 8  |    1   |    2   +
+ 9  |    0   |    3   +
+ 10 |    1   |    3   +
+ 11 |    1   |    2   +
+----------------------+
```

What I want:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
+ id | status | people | positionTotal | positionSamePeople  +
+------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 1  |    1   |    3   |       1       |          1          +
+ 4  |    1   |    3   |       2       |          2          +
+ 6  |    1   |    1   |       3       |          1          +
+ 8  |    1   |    2   |       4       |          1          +
+ 10 |    1   |    3   |       5       |          3          +
+ 11 |    1   |    2   |       6       |          2          +
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can query `SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE status=1` and then calculate the `positionTotal` and `positionSamePeople` in PHP, but it seems not a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with subqueries:

```
SELECT r1.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) +1
   FROM reservation r2
   WHERE r2.status = 1
     AND r2.id < r1.id) AS positionTotal,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) +1
   FROM reservation r3
   WHERE r3.status = 1
     AND r3.people = r1.people
     AND r3.id < r1.id) AS positionSamePeople
FROM reservation r1
```